# update URL endpoint of specific via sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I would like to replace a line of this file **/Users/jdoe/Sites/vue/app/public/index.html**

from

window.API_URL = "anything"

to

`window.API_URL = "http://api.local:1234`

## I tried :

```
sed -i -e 's/.*window.API_URL.*/window.API_URL = "http://api.local:1234"/g' /Users/jdoe/Sites/vue/app/public/index.html
```

Kept getting

> sed: 1: "s/.*window.API_URL.*/wi ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

you need the `\` to escape the `/` in the url, this should work:

`sed -i -e 's/.*window.API_URL.*/window.API_URL = "http:\/\/api.local:1234"/g' index.html`

also if you prefer awk:

`awk  -i inplace '/window.API_URL/ {$3=" \"http://api.local:1234\""} 1' index.html`